# The design from following css is not appearing as expected in Mozilla firefox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, web-testing

I have a CSS as given below.

```
.controlledline4 {
   display: -webkit-box;
  overflow : hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
}
```

but the design by above CSS is appearing perfectly in Chrome but in Mozilla Firefox it is not appearing clearly.
Note: The above code is to hide lengthy text and show only few lines of beginning of text.

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla uses the *-moz* CSS attribute.
Chrome and Safari use *-webkit*. IE9+ use *-ms*.

Modify your CSS as below:

```
.controlledline4 {
   display: -webkit-box;
  overflow : hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -moz-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;  
}
```

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS using box is outdated, and one should use the flex as below:

```
.controlledline4 {

   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: -moz-flex;
  overflow : hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -moz-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;  
  -moz-flex-direction: column;  
}
```